# Help me understand when, why and how to edit posts

Tags: support, review-queues

I recently had [an edit rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10080843) and am not *exactly* sure why this happened. I tried not to change the user's question at all, but just provide a clearer representation of the question for future visitors.

In the past, I've made an [edit that corrects spelling and grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10071349), and it has been accepted.

I've referenced [the help section for editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and in my opinion, *which can very well be wrong*, states a case for my edit that was rejected.

> To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)

I always try my best to not change the meaning when editing so far, but perhaps I did or went too overboard on the edit. The reason given seems a little abstract to me.

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I'd very much like *not* to make the same mistake again and figure out what I did wrong.

Is there an article that explains to newer users, when *not* to edit? I guess logically it would be if it doesn't fall under the aforementioned reasons, but perhaps an article that goes into details explaining why an edit is bad or good.

Comment: The approved edit that you list was very minor, in comparison to the one which was rejected. It was a bit of a drastic edit, which may have thrown people off a little bit.

Comment: @Zizouz212 i openly admit it was a lil extreme, but i thought/think I didn't change the question at all, just made it more clear (possibly too much), but I thought if it was laid out like that it would help future visitors more -- if an edit doesn't change the question but majorly changes the layout of the question, is that a reason for rejection?

Comment: Yeah, I understand. You really need to look at it very in-depth, since I assume that you had a few things (like use of `.animate()` which you added) which was taken from reading the code. On really close thought, it should've been approved, but I'm not surprised that it was rejected entirely. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Ok, I got it. It's one of my first edit rejections, so it was making me apprehensive about making more edits; I thought maybe I was editing things that *shouldn't* be - should I avoid re-writing poorly written questions in the future?

Comment: Oh no! Keep editing questions, don't let this discourage you! Of the 43 suggested edits that I've had, I've had 10 rejected, so you're definitely not alone. Continue editing :D

Comment: @Zizouz212 Ok, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :D

Comment: That was a much larger change that drastically changed the question, and reviewers don't (and should not usually) like major changes to a post. It's very difficult to determine whether you changed the meaning of the post drastically, and if I saw the amount of changes you made without being able to clearly see where you (at least thought) you were pulling up the information, I'd have rejected the edit as well. I see content in your edit that I can't determine where it came from, because it certainly isn't contained in the post itself.

Comment: Your change *looks* like a radical change, even though it isn't. Take more care with the description, and (at least if you have sufficient reason to believe the robo-reviewers will reject, or even reasonably careful reviewers, like in this case), consider asking in an appropriate chat-room to make sure your extraordinarily thorough edit won't get killed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick glance at the post highlights why one *might* have rejected it - it changed **a lot of stuff**.  It's unfortunate that the edit wasn't really perused; you've preserved much of the original intent without any of the jittery English.

Don't let this edit get you down; personally I think you did alright with it.  It makes the question clearer and more concise.

In the future:  persevere.  Things like this will happen, and I don't want to lose someone who's passionate and thorough with their edits because they were senselessly rejected once or twice.  Consider also getting 2K rep so your edits don't have to go through the edit queue.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I plan on continuing to participate; although I have been a bit more careful/hesitant with my edits, but maybe that's not such a bad thing.

Comment: @Quoid You should continue doing the great work, and contribute to the community. You should see the brighter side, you always had your edits accepted, this was just your first edit rejection.

Comment: Er....but everyone rejected it as "attempt to reply." I would have expected people rejecting it for being "too major" to have marked it as "clearly conflicts with author's intent."