# Should I simply leave very low quality posts unedited?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

Today I edited two questions ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37101638/revisions), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37098832/revisions)) and both edits got approved with a 3 to 2 approval rate, which I consider quite bad. This clearly shows that 40% of reviewers think that what I do is simply not useful, and it takes 66% more effort to have my edits approved. Probably I am overthinking this, but since one of the reviewers is a rather high-profile SO user (so that his vote weights somewhat more than of those who are doing this since yesterday), I figured I can come forward and ask about this here.

In #1 I added a tag, capitalized *Hamiltonian* and broke the two-line-long sentence into two parts. While I was there, I also removed noise. This wasn't that bad post, but still could have used some polishing.

If #2 were a first post, that would have been classified unsalvageable or blatantly off-topic by high probability. But since it made it to the front page, *and* received an answer already, I figured that I can put some sense into it. I indeed made quite some changes, but the post looked very bad.

So, I am asking the community, and especially the reviewers (although it is again unlikely that they will see this post) to guide me how to get better approval rate considering my edits.

One thing I can think of is that the edits (and the reviews) were "waste of time" as the posts are very low quality and will likely be removed sometimes in the near future anyways. However, if this is the case, then the reason for rejection *should be something else* other than:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

It goes without saying that I strongly disagree with *the specified reason* of rejection regarding my edits. But maybe the reason is something else. *Should I simply leave very low quality posts unedited?*

---

Related: [Help me understand when, why and how to edit posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309422/help-me-understand-when-why-and-how-to-edit-posts) and [The "How to Edit" section should also clarify what not to do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292046/the-how-to-edit-section-should-also-clarify-what-not-to-do)

Comment: ***TL; DR;*** Don't polish turds ...

Comment: #1 is now closed.

Comment: FWIW, although the "does not make the post even a little bit easier to read" message isn't very accurate it's probably the most appropriate choice when someone has suggested an edit on unsalvageable rubbish.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Leaving aside the question of the two specific examples you cite, it seems to me that the question of editing comes down to: can you turn the post into a *useful* question that will get the answer the author wants?

Both elements are important. First, many questions ask for answers that the author of the question wants, but the question itself just isn't useful to anyone else. Archiving a question like that on Stack Overflow is a waste; it just clutters up the search results and makes it harder to find questions that *are* useful.

Second, you need to make sure you can improve the question to the point that it can elicit *answers*, and where those answers can actually solve the problem the question's author needs solved. Naturally, this means you'd better be able to understand yourself what the question is. Many low quality questions are just incomprehensible.

Editing a question in a way that dresses it up, but still leaves it non-functional is not useful or helpful.

All that said, I'll point out that the suggested edits queue is somewhat orthogonal to the above. Many reviewers may not care whether there's any *point* to editing the post, as long as you've done *something* to improve it. Others may reject your edit arbitrarily or at least for reasons that are unrelated to any of this. You've asked a specific question here, i.e. *"should I edit low quality posts"*, and that's what I've answered. But that does not necessarily address the question of how to have fewer reject votes from the review queue.

Even so, do consider that *"more accurate or more accessible"* (as stated in the reject vote reason you quoted) can be construed to address the question of comprehensibility and usefulness. I.e. if the original post was incomprehensible and/or not useful, and your edit failed to change that, then that does seem like that would be a reasonable reason to reject the edit.

Comment: One reason to reject edits to low-quality posts is that editing bumps it. If the post cannot be salvaged, it should be closed/flagged.

Comment: @S.L.: agreed. However, the review queue does not offer judgments on the original post as a reason to reject an _edit_. Technically, rejections of edits should be limited to reasons listed by the reject prompt. "Cannot be salvaged" isn't one of those reasons. One could argue an unsalvageable post isn't and cannot be improved by any edit, justifying the use of "no improvement whatsoever". I know I would. But that's definitely heading into subjective territory.

Comment: _Many low quality questions are just incomprehensible._ sums it up pretty well.

Comment: All right. Of course, this attitude towards these posts raises a whole lot of other questions (and possible answers) I should dig up here or on the main site. I thank you for your time posting this answer.

Answer (score 20):

#1 was clearly off-topic, since it asked for off-site resources, and your time could have been spent better. But I think you did good work on both of them. You managed to bring forth the qualities of #2! It goes without saying that editing posts that are going to get closed anyway is a waste of time, unless you think you can salvage it to a point where it can be reopened again (e.g., there is actually an on-topic question hiding in there). Personally I would have accepted both your edits because they did leave the questions in a better state than before.

Comment: #2 looks like a homework dump.

Comment: @S.L.Barth A non-coding homework dump at that...

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, should it have been migrated to math.SE?

Comment: @FranklinYu No. We don't migrate bad content. Until the OP edits it and shows what they've tried, it won't be welcome anywhere on SE.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's overlooked that users can learn from edited posts, new users can be unsure what writing style is expected or how to word and format their questions correctly. I personally think that editing first posts that make sense is a good thing. The fact that both questions seem to be closed for whatever reason and unwelcome doesn't change the fact that you will see posts like those here and those people will continue to post and if they get question banned they might simply make a new account and move on. (Your edit can potentially pay off in the long run if they learn something)

The question is how much time did you spend and was it worth it ? The answer is that you probably took less than 1-2 minutes formatting each and gave the people indirect precise feedback on what to potentially improve. Both people already have 6 questions each and are likely going to post more. If they learn over time and feedback is productive, they will learn their mistakes. If their questions are looking well formatted they are more likely to realize their questions are not ontopic or they are not closed/downvotes for formatting/grammar. They are less worried about formatting/grammar (because they are gaining more experience of the correct way to do it) and can focus on the content of the question.

Both posted topics are borderline ontopic according to the help-section but subjectively perceived to be offtopic and unwelcome. The posters are likely to be confused and removing the formatting mistakes, assures them that their topics are at fault and not their formatting skills.

I think your time is well spend as long as you don't invest/"waste" to much time. Many people will disagree with me and say "gtfo from stackoverflow, those people don't belong here, no don't help them", but thruth is helping them to post better/realize their mistakes benefits the community and you are doing that indirectly.

If you want to help more leave a somewhat detailed-feedback on the close reason, so they understand in detail why their borderline things don't fit into the rules. People assume they haven't read any but that isn't necessarily true, fact is the rules are very vague and somewhat subjective, especially in bordercases.

Comment: A comment on the posts would have been a much better way to give feedback - more direct and more clear. It also doesn't require 3 reviewers, like edit suggestions do.

Comment: You are right, but the feedback needs to be beyond the scope of simply point to the FAQ and if OP isn't voting to close he doesn't know it before it's closed. On the other hand an edit is helpful if something isn't closed or only closed because of bad grammar/formatting that obscures the questions intention. Edits doing simply formatting or grammar corrections take only the time of reading and typing for the writer, which isn't much longer than reading itself, while thinking about whether or not a question is closed and explaining it to someone can take more time to think about

Answer (score -11):

Recently one of my post got 'edited' for trifles, that is minor —albeit relevant— typo details that could by no means improve its readability or its overall linguistic appropriateness. (Sorry I have not kept track of it for the sake of individual opinions).

I was then surprised to observe that the 'editor' gained marks for her action and I now wonder whether there might be 'marks chasers' through insipid editing? Be that as it may I should think editing must restrict strictly to making a post more legible or readable —which is imperative in certain cases as we all admit.